# Pandas DataFrame replace does not work with inplace=True

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, data-science

In my column of the data frame i have version numbers like 6.3.5, 1.8, 5.10.0 saved as objects and thus likely as Strings. I want to remove the dots with nothing so i get 635, 18, 5100. My code idea was this:

```
for row in dataset.ver:
    row.replace(".","",inplace=True)
```

The thing is it works if I don't set inplace to True, but we want to overwrite it and safe it.

Comment: Please show a sample of your dataframe, it helps very much to come up with a solution.  Furthermore it's best to use vectorized operations, not a for loop like you're maybe used to in pure python. A vectorized solution in pandas would be for example be like this: dataset['ver'].replace("[.]","", inplace=True, regex=True).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're iterating through the elements within the `DataFrame`, in which case I'm assuming it's type `str` (or being coerced to `str` when you `replace`).  `str.replace` doesn't have an argument for `inplace=...`.

You should be doing this instead:

```
dataset['ver'] = dataset['ver'].str.replace('.', '')
```

Comment: `df.col_name =` on an existing column can have bad behavior instead use `df['col_name'] =`

Comment: Yeah I had it that way to match OP's style, but I changed it during your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Sander van den Oord in the comments is quite correct to point out:

```
dataset['ver'].replace("[.]","", inplace=True, regex=True)
```

This is the way we do operations on a column in Pandas because in general, Pandas tries to optimize over `for` loops. The Pandas developers consider for loops the among least desirable pattern for row-wise operations in Python (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html).)