# Why pandas DataFrame replace method does not work (inplace=True argument is used)

Tags: python, dataframe, str-replace

I convert a CSV file to pandas DataFrame, but found all content is str with the pattern like ="**content**"

Tried using **df.replace** to substitute '=' and '"'. The code is like

```
df.replace("=","", inplace = True)
df.replace('"',"", inplace = True)
```

However, this code does not work without error messages, and nothing is replaced in the Dataframe.

[After df.replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru2t7.png)

Strangely, it works when use

`df[column] = df[column].str.replace('=','')`

`df[column] = df[column].str.replace('=','')`

Is there any possible way to replace/substitute equal and double quote signs using DataFrame methods? And I am curious with the reason why df.replace method isn't workable.

Sorry I can only provide the pic since the original data and code are in a notebook with locked internet and USB function.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame replace does not work with inplace=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634718/pandas-dataframe-replace-does-not-work-with-inplace-true)

Comment: @Thekingis007  Yes, I know per column-wise, the replace method is workable. I am curious if there is any way to delete '=' and ' " ' using dataframe methods as replace or substitute like dataframe.replace("=","",inplace=True)

Comment: Add `inplace=True` to the accepted answer here: [Replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.replace('=', '')` requires the cell value to be exactly `'='` which is obviously not true in your case.

You may instead use it with `regex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['="abc"', '="bcd"'], 'b': ['="uef"', '="hdd"'], 'c':[1,3]})
df.replace([r'^="', r'"$'], '', regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)

     a    b  c
0  abc  uef  1
1  bcd  hdd  3
```

Two regular expressions are used here, with the first taking care of the head and the second the tail.

Comment: thanks I will try it when I get off work. Still curious why df[column] = df[column].str.replace('=','') works while df.replace("=","", inplace = True) not

Comment: They are just different things. `pd.DataFrame.replace` and `pd.Series.replace` are for whole-cell replacement that works for both string and ***number***, where as `pd.Series.str.replace` is sub-string replacement. I think you wanted `pd.DataFrame.str.replace` but it's not provided.